# How to solve Maven connection exception error

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

Can someone help me out with this problem ... i have spent too much time with this error but couldnt solve this ...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:
deploy (default-cli) on project HelloMaven: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection to http:// localhost:8080 refused: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http:// cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ConnectException
```

Following is my pom.xml :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.abc.app</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloMaven</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>HelloMaven Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>HelloMaven</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/HelloMaven</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Could you add the content from your pom.xml?

Comment: Probably you don't have a tomcat running locally... or it's not listening on port 8080. Maybe (if the project is configured properly) you can run `mvn tomcat7:run` and that will run an embedded tomcat.

Comment: @reporter i have added pom.xml... please do have a look

Comment: @Augusto : i have tried all this but everytime this is the error

Answer (score 0):

1. First clarify which version of Tomcat you are running. It's essentially important because configuration is sligthly different. I will describe it for Tomcat 7.
2. Define a new user in your tomcat-user.xml and assign it the privilege "manager-script". This user should have no other manager-...-Roles.
3. Open your pom.xml and change the configuration of your tomcat7-plugin. Change the url to http:// localhost:8080/manager/text. Keep in mind that you use the text-console and not the html-console.
4. Goto your settings.xml and check, that there is a server-configuration with the corresponding id that you use in your tomcat7-plugin-configuration.
   for example:

```xml
<server>
    <id>TomcatServer</id>
    <username>scriptuser</username>
    <password>mypassword</password>
</server>
```

Comment: I don't think that because you just have to declare an active profile in your settings.

Comment: I think so, because a connection refused error points to wrong username, password or missspelled server-id.

Comment: @shylynx i have already tried all the steps mentioned by you but still of no use.

Comment: Can you connect over telnet?